# How to setup include_path in xampp install for mac

Tags: php, macos, xampp

it's my first time setting up xampp on mac.  When I run my page, I receive the error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'inc_db_init.php' (include_path='.:/home/site/includes') in /Volumes/untitled/Websites/site/www/test/index.php on line ...
```

In my phpInfo() printout it shows this

```
include_path    .:/home/site/includes   .:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php
```

The include_path is wrong. I need it to be

```
\Volumes\untitled\Websites\site\test_includes
```

The php.ini path shown in phpInfo() is this:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
```

So when I open up that file, there is no include_path set anywhere.

I have another php.ini file in the directory from which the pages are in but it is not being picked up.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So, I installed the basic installation of xampp. It was using my .htaccess file instead of my php.ini file to determine the include_path

This is the line I had to insert into my .htaccess file

```
php_value include_path ".:/Volumes/untitled/Websites/site/test_includes"
```